# Reading in csv file as dataframe from hdfs

Tags: python, hadoop, pandas, hdfs

I'm using pydoop to read in a file from hdfs, and when I use:

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hd
with hd.open("/home/file.csv") as f:
    print f.read()
```

It shows me the file in stdout.

Is there any way for me to read in this file as dataframe? I've tried using pandas' read_csv("/home/file.csv"), but it tells me that the file cannot be found. The exact code and error is:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv("/home/file.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 498, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 275, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 590, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 731, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1103, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 353, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:3246)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 591, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/parser.c:6111)
IOError: File /home/file.csv does not exist
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know next to nothing about `hdfs`, but I wonder if the following might work:

```
with hd.open("/home/file.csv") as f:
    df =  pd.read_csv(f)
```

I assume `read_csv` works with a file handle, or in fact any iterable that will feed it lines.  I know the `numpy` csv readers do.

`pd.read_csv("/home/file.csv")` would work if the regular Python file `open` works - i.e. it reads the file a regular local file.

```
with open("/home/file.csv") as f: 
    print f.read()
```

But evidently `hd.open` is using some other location or protocol, so the file is not local.  If my suggestion doesn't work, then you (or we) need to dig more into the `hdfs` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code to read csv from hdfs

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
hdfs_config = {
     "host" : "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
     "port" : 8020,
     "user" : "user"
}
fs = pa.hdfs.connect(hdfs_config['host'], hdfs_config['port'], 
user=hdfs_config['user'])
df=pd.read_csv(fs.open("/home/file.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `read` instead `open`, it works

```py
with hd.read("/home/file.csv") as f:
    df =  pd.read_csv(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write with pyarrow natively. I found the pydoop library to be a bit clumsy and require lots of annoying dependencies. The syntax is as follows:

```
from pyarrow import fs
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# connect to hadoop
hdfs = fs.HadoopFileSystem('hostname', 8020) 

# will read single file from hdfs
with hdfs.open_input_file(path) as pqt:
     df = pq.read_table(pqt).to_pandas()

# will read directory full of partitioned parquets (ie. from spark)
df = pq.ParquetDataset(path, hdfs).read().to_pandas()
```