# Python : How to import list of files in directory from HDFS

Tags: python, hdfs

I try to import list of files from **HDFS** in python.

How to do this from HDFS :

```
path =r'/my_path'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

df_list = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0,sep=';')    
    df_list.append(df)
```

I think **subprocess.Popen** do the trick but how to extract only the filename ?

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("hdfs dfs -ls /my_path/ ",
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)


for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print(line)
```

The output is like this :

```
b'Found 32 items\n'
b'-rw-------   3 user hdfs   42202621 2019-01-21 10:05 /my_path/file1.csv\n'
b'-rw-------   3 user hdfs   99320020 2019-01-21 10:05 /my_path/file2.csv\n'
```

Comment: Any reason to not use external libraries, such as [HdfsCLI](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: Yes I dont have permission to install external librairies

Comment: BTW, `pd.read_csv` won't work either. If you want to pull data from hdfs using `pandas`, you need to pass _webhdfs_ downloadable link, not just file path; `pandas` will search the path in the local, and will raise `FileNotFoundError`

Comment: Thanks ! This refer to this link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642020/reading-in-csv-file-as-dataframe-from-hdfs

Comment: The link also utilizes an external library. Do you have an access to webhdfs?

Comment: Sorry how can I check this ?

Comment: Trying accessing http://[your-namenode-ip]:50070

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have access. There are no other ways?

Comment: If I have access to it, how to import it easily in python ? I try to access it by an other user.

Comment: please refer to my long and boring answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Declaimer**: This will be a long and tedious. But given the circumstance, I'll try to make it as general and reproducible as possible.

---

Given the requirement of no external libraries (except for `pandas`?), there isn't must of a choice to take. I suggest utilizing `WebHDFS` as much as possible.

AFAIK, installation of *HDFS*, by default, includes an installation of *WebHDFS*. Following solution heavily relies on *WebHDFS*.

#### First Step

To begin with, you must be aware of *WebHDFS* urls. *WebHDFS* is installed on **HDFS Namenode(s)**, and default port is **50070**.

Therefore, we start with `http://[namenode_ip]:50070/webhdfs/v1/`, where `/webhdfs/v1`/ is a common url for all.

For the sake of example, let's assume it as `http://192.168.10.1:50070/web/hdfs/v1`.

#### Second Step

Ordinarily, one can use `curl` to list contents of a HDFS directory.
For detailed explanation, refer to [WebHDFS REST API: List a Directory](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#LISTSTATUS)

If you were to use `curl`, following provides `FileStatuses` of all the files inside a given directory.

```
curl "http://192.168.10.1:50070/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=LISTSTATUS"
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^             ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             Namenode IP  Port              Path  Operation
```

As mentioned, this returns FileStatuses in JSON object:

```
{
  "FileStatuses":
  {
    "FileStatus":
    [
      {
        "accessTime"      : 1320171722771,
        "blockSize"       : 33554432,
        "group"           : "supergroup",
        "length"          : 24930,
        "modificationTime": 1320171722771,
        "owner"           : "webuser",
        "pathSuffix"      : "a.patch",
        "permission"      : "644",
        "replication"     : 1,
        "type"            : "FILE"
      },
      {
        "accessTime"      : 0,
        "blockSize"       : 0,
        "group"           : "supergroup",
        "length"          : 0,
        "modificationTime": 1320895981256,
        "owner"           : "szetszwo",
        "pathSuffix"      : "bar",
        "permission"      : "711",
        "replication"     : 0,
        "type"            : "DIRECTORY"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Same result can be achieved using python's default libs:

```
import requests

my_path = '/my_path/'
curl = requests.get('http://192.168.10.1:50070/webhdfs/v1/%s?op=LISTSTATUS' % my_path)
```

And as shown above, the actual status of each file is two levels below of the result JSON. In other words, to get the FileStatus of each file:

```
curl.json()['FileStatuses']['FileStatus'] 

[
  {
    "accessTime"      : 1320171722771,
    "blockSize"       : 33554432,
    "group"           : "supergroup",
    "length"          : 24930,
    "modificationTime": 1320171722771,
    "owner"           : "webuser",
    "pathSuffix"      : "a.patch",
    "permission"      : "644",
    "replication"     : 1,
    "type"            : "FILE"
  },
  {
    "accessTime"      : 0,
    "blockSize"       : 0,
    "group"           : "supergroup",
    "length"          : 0,
    "modificationTime": 1320895981256,
    "owner"           : "szetszwo",
    "pathSuffix"      : "bar",
    "permission"      : "711",
    "replication"     : 0,
    "type"            : "DIRECTORY"
  },
  ...
]
```

#### Third Step

Since you now have all the information you want, all you need to do is parsing.

```
import os

file_paths = []
for file_status in curl.json()['FileStatuses']['FileStatus']:
    file_name = file_status['pathSuffix']
    # this is the file name in the queried directory
    if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
    # if statement is only required if the directory contains unwanted files (i.e. non-csvs).
        file_paths.append(os.path.join(path, file_name))
        # os.path.join asserts your result consists of absolute path

file_paths
['/my_path/file1.csv',
 '/my_path/file2.csv',
 ...]
```

#### Final Step

Now you know the paths of files and WebHDFS links, `pandas.read_csv` can handle rest of the works.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
web_url = "http://192.168.10.1:50070/webhdfs/v1/%s?op=OPEN"
#                                                  ^^^^^^^
#                                    Operation is now OPEN
for file_path in file_paths:
    file_url = web_url % file_path
    # http://192.168.10.1:50070/webhdfs/v1/my_path/file1.csv?op=OPEN
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file_url))
```

And there you go with all the `.csv`s imported and assigned to `dfs`.

#### Warnings

If your HDFS is configured for **HA** (High Availability), there will be multiple **namenodes** and thus your `namenode_ip` must be set accordingly: It must be the IP of an active node.

Comment: Thanks, very clear !  However I have this error when I execute curl -i : 

     <title>Error 401 Authentication required</title>
     </head>
     <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>
     <p>Problem accessing /webhdfs/v1/data/my_path/. Reason:
     <pre> Authentication required</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by 
     Jetty://</small></i><br/>

Comment: @CoxTox That is http issue. This link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044315/how-to-set-the-authorization-header-using-curl

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to this question is the worst possible approach I could imagine and a crime against humanity. You can read and write with pyarrow natively. The syntax is as follows:

```
from pyarrow import fs
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# connect to hadoop
hdfs = fs.HadoopFileSystem('hostname', 8020) 

# will read single file from hdfs
with hdfs.open_input_file(path) as pqt:
     df = pq.read_table(pqt).to_pandas()

# will read directory full of partitioned parquets (ie. from spark)
df = pq.ParquetDataset(path, hdfs).read().to_pandas()
```