# Pyspark : Convert a CSV to Nested JSON

Tags: python, json, csv, hadoop, pyspark

I am new to pyspark. I have a requirement where I need to convert a big CSV file at hdfs location to multiple Nested JSON files based on distinct primaryId.

**Sample Input:** data.csv

```
**PrimaryId,FirstName,LastName,City,CarName,DogName**
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Rusty
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Rusty
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Max
102,Julia,Brown,London,Mini,Lucy
```

**Sample Output Files:**

**File1:** Output_100.json

```
{
    "100": [
        {
            "City": "NewYork", 
            "FirstName": "John", 
            "LastName": "Smith", 
            "CarName": [
                "Toyota", 
                "BMW"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Spike", 
                "Rusty"
            ]
        }
}
```

**File2:** Output_101.json

```
{
    "101": [
        {
            "City": "Sydney", 
            "FirstName": "Ben", 
            "LastName": "Swan", 
            "CarName": [
                "Volkswagen", 
                "Ford", 
                "Audi"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Buddy", 
                "Max"
            ]
        }
}
```

**File3:** Output_102.json

```
{
    "102": [
        {
            "City": "London", 
            "FirstName": "Julia", 
            "LastName": "Brown", 
            "CarName": [
                "Mini"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Lucy"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any quick help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try sth. already? You could generate a set of Primary IDs and iterate over every entry then, generating an array of dictionaries.

Comment: I am not really from programming background and tried few solutions from google but that won't fulfill my requirement. That is why I am looking for help !!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to perform a group by on Id and collect Cars and Dogs as a set.

from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("cars.csv")
df2 = (
    df
    .groupBy("PrimaryId","FirstName","LastName")
    .agg(collect_set('CarName').alias('CarName'), collect_set('DogName').alias('DogName'))
)
df2.write.format("json").save("cars.json", mode="overwrite")
```

Generated files:

```
{"PrimaryId":"100","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Smith","CarName":["Toyota","BMW"],"DogName":["Spike","Rusty"]}

{"PrimaryId":"101","FirstName":"Ben","LastName":"Swan","CarName":["Ford","Volkswagen","Audi"],"DogName":["Max","Buddy"]}

{"PrimaryId":"102","FirstName":"Julia","LastName":"Brown","CarName":["Mini"],"DogName":["Lucy"]}
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That is just a sample File I have to use this code on actual file contain 40-50 fields with millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.groupby()` to group by the Id and then iterate over the `DataFrameGroupBy` object creating the objects and writing the files.

You need to install pandas by `$ pip install pandas` to your virtualenv.

```
# coding: utf-8
import json
import pandas as pd


def group_csv_columns(csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    group_frame = df.groupby(['PrimaryId'])

    for i in group_frame:
        data_frame = i[1]
        data = {}
        data[i[0]] = [{
            "City": data_frame['City'].unique().tolist()[0],
            "FirstName": data_frame['FirstName'].unique().tolist()[0],
            "CarName": data_frame['CarName'].unique().tolist(),
            'DogName': data_frame['DogName'].unique().tolist(),
            'LastName': data_frame['LastName'].unique().tolist()[0],
        }]
        # Write to file
        file_name = 'Output_' + str(i[0]) + '.json'
        with open(file_name, 'w') as fh:
            contents = json.dumps(data)
            fh.write(contents)


group_csv_columns('/tmp/sample.csv')
```

Call the `group_csv_columns()` with the file_name with the csv contents.

Check the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: Can we put hdfs path as input/output instead of local file system ?

Comment: You can try `with hd.open("/home/file.csv") as f:
    df =  pd.read_csv(f)` , check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35644136/1831811

Comment: Sure will try with that but I am think this code should be efficient on hadoop environment.